# Nested table overflowing outer parent table and also the scroll bar for the nested table is showing up in the outer table

Tags: html, css

I've added a simpler example in jsfiddle for the code I've got at the moment
https://jsfiddle.net/ms3n6o2r/42/

I have 2 issues, the first is that the inner table has more columns than the outer one and it ends up over flowing. I want to make it so that it is the same width as the outer one (75% of window) and then any extra columns to be viewed by scrolling using the scroll bar.

The second issue is that the horizontal scrollbar seems to be showing up in the parent table. I'm assuming this is linked to the first issue since the inner table overflows outside of the outer table.

```
.container{
  width: 75%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  height: 75vh;
}

.container table{
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.container table, tr td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.container tbody {
  z-index: 0;
  display: block;
  max-height: 70vh;
  overflow: auto;
}

.container table, thead, tbody, tr {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.container thead, tr, th{
  margin: 5px;
}
.container .static-first-column{
  width: 20px;
}
.container .static-last-column{
  width: 130px;
}
.container .final-table
{
  width: 200%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.container .final-tbody{
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
  max-height: 70vh;
  overflow: auto;
}
.container .final-table .final-thead .final-tbody .final-tr
{
  width:100%;
}
```

**EDIT 1**

I forgot to mention that the reason I had set the width to 200% in the child table is so that all the text within the td can be on a single line instead of it wrapping the text.

**EDIT 2**
I would like for the red bar to be as long as the green bar and for the green bar to not exist. The red bar moves the inner table but only slightly whereas the green bar moves the outer table. When sliding the green bar you will see that the inner table expands outside of the outer table.

[image: Table example]

[image: Inner table expands beyond outer table]

**EDIT 3**
After following Byle's answer and Eye-Wonder's comment (within his answer) I'm left with 2 scroll bars. One barely moves the table whereas the other moves it entirely.

[image: Remove this scroll bar]

Comment: its best to include a snippet (with html) in the question for it to be useful for future generations

Comment: Thanks, but Stackoverflow ends up complaining about there being too much code and not enough of an explanation for it which is why I omitted it. It's in the jsfiddle link anyway.

Comment: I spent the last hour trying to debug this but honestly it'd be a hackish fix. If i were you id check out the MDN Web docs on how to do nested tables properly and redo the whole thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the tables is set to 200% width. They will align more if you change to 100%. Also try a HTML validator. That will tell you if your HTML is valid or not. tr > div > table does not look right.

Comment: I had forgot to mention that in the second table I wanted the column names/tds in one line instead of it wrapping the text. I'll edit the question to include that. Also on https://jsonformatter.org/html-validator it states the html is valid.

Comment: If you lock the table width, to avoid text from wrapping, you probably want to move the overflow: auto; from tbody to the surrounding div element.

Comment: Brilliant! It's very close to what I need. For some reason now it seems that there's 2 horizontal scroll bars although I had removed it from tbody and applied it to the div. Take a look at Edit 3 please.

Comment: Sorted it out I had to put in overflow:hidden into .container .final-tbody otherwise it would inherit overflow:auto from .container tbody. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is youre wrapping the nested table in a `div` instead of a `td` which when you look in the chrome debugger the browsers autocorrects to the nested table not being nested anymore but below it like this:

[image: html structure]

Comment: Thanks, I did that and now the table is nested within the outer table but there's still the issue with the size and the scrollbar. I've edited my question to mention that I'd like for the text to be in a single line instead of it wrapping the text hence why one property's width = 200%.